# Incidence of vias in the middle of a net

Tags: pcb

Talking only about power and not interferences or inductance/capacitance, and taking note that all copper loosed by the hole is gained by the cilinder inside it, what is the incidence of vias in the middle of a net and not on a branch?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean with "incidence". Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don’t think there is a general data base of such things. Why would this be of interest?

Comment: Do you mean *how it affects*?

Comment: Sorry, yes, i want to mean "how it affects"

Comment: @danirebollo, please edit your question to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. Do you mean "lost" instead of "loosed"? Do you mean "impedance" instead of "incidence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want significant power supply current to flow through a via, you must make sure that it has sufficient total copper area. You can ask the PCB manufacturer what the minimum wall thickness is for their vias.

When I've designed boards, I've usually assumed that with standard processing, so starting out with 1/2oz / 17um copper plating up to 35um, the via will end up with at least 17um wall thickness as well. This is probably optimistic, though the via is very short and is heat-sunk by copper traces at both ends, so is unlikely to overheat even if it is a bit thin.

A common technique is to use multiple parallel vias when you have significant current flow. If concerned, then compare the voltage drop along a few mm of a high current trace with the voltage drop from one side to the other. If the latter is excessive, then you need more vias.

If you treat a via as a piece of track which is twice as wide as the via, then it's probably about right. If the track needs to be wide to carry your current, then connect it with as many vias as will fit into the width of the track.

Comment: Thanks Neil, interesting answer.

Comment: Can we summarize the "best design rules" in: "for power use vias in parallel, for signal it is ok to place vias in the middle of a net"? In my designs power nets usually has some vias in parallel, and also usually has star design, but I'm afraid of being increasing the impedance of a signal trace because the using of some layer changes in the same net without split into branches. I dont know if makes any sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. Treat a via as a piece of track perhaps twice the diameter of the via. Ignore stars, 'middle' of a net etc. If you'd connect two bits of track with a track, then you can connect two bits of track with a via.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about placing vias on the net itself, rather than taking a branch, the implication is not much if it is a simple data signal. If it is a power track, make sure there is enough width of the track to sustain the current. The vias will not be a negative thing.

Placing the testpoints direktly on the net rather than taking a branch for it also have advantages in signal integrity.